# I wish to create a batch file which should copy the contents of all text files present into a single file

Tags: batch-file

I tried doing `copy *.txt "Final.txt"` but I want a new line after every file being copied.

Answer (score 1):

Contents of `your_file.bat`:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do type %%a >> final.txt & echo. >> final.txt
```

`echo.` is to add empty line. `&` is command separator in batch file. `>>` is append to text file and `>` will create new `final.txt` each time.

PS: It is good to put `final.txt` in different directory or use another extension e.g. `final.doc` otherwise `final.txt` contents will be added to the result.

Answer (score 1):

taking "a new line after every file" not too literal, `type *.txt >final.txt  2>&1` could do (it adds the filename in front of every file). To answer your question literally: `copy` alone can't do that. You have to iterate over the files and append the contents plus an empty line to the resulting file:

```
(for %%A in (*.txt) do (
  type %%a
  echo/
))>final.tmp
ren final.tmp final.txt
```

Only redirecting once is much faster than opening, writing and closing the file for every file and every empty line (you won't notice it with only some files, but it can make a difference if you have many files)

Hint: Instead of an empty line (`echo/`) you could also easlily do some more obvious, like
`echo ====== %%A ======`, which will add an title with the filename before each file (same like
`type *.txt >final.txt  2>&1`, but more visible).